# Select * distinct one column

Tags: php, mysql, distinct

I have mysql table tmp with columns pid,city,state,country. I write queries so i can find matching city,state or country, and pid is field that helps me load another table.
The thing is, there is always two rows with same pid, and sometimes (when WHERE find matching city state or country in both), i display data from additional table twice unnecessarily.
So i need to select something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tmp DISTINCT pid WHERE city='test'
```

I have no idea how to search solution (i searched here on stackoverflow, but no luck).
Also, there will be a lot of searching in this table, so if there is multiple solutions i would prefer one that is faster.
Thanks

Comment: I wonder you got nothing on Google for "mysql select * distinct one column"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT pid,field1,field2 FROM tmp WHERE city='test'
```

Comment: I guess that this is solution, is this much slower than SELECT * FROM tmp WHERE city='test'?

Comment: this will work as selecting the records with distinct pid, and will select other fields as well .. as you mentioned in comment below.. :) happy coding

Answer (score 4):

Please try the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT pid FROM tmp WHERE city='test'
```

Comment: Forgot that enter enters comment :). This will work, but i would like if there is a way to select all columns? But the only distinct value should be pid

Comment: @Milos911: Do you want all columns but only rows that having `DISTINCT pid`? So, if two (or more) rows have same `pid`, which one should be returned?

Comment: Any can be returned, since with pid i load second table called projects. I think i found right solution, SELECT DISTINCT tmp.pid,project.* LEFT JOIN project ON project.pid=tmp.pid. This works, but i am not sure if it is correct to do it this way?

Comment: And, yes, i would like to know if there is a way to select all columns in one table, but only pid should be distinct?

Answer (score -1):

```
$keyword="0";
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT titel,id FROM xyz ORDER BY titel ASC ";
$result = mysql_query($query); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{ 
    if($keyword!==$row["titel"])
    {
        $keyword=$row["titel"];
        echo $keyword;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. When posting a code snippet in your answer, please also consider adding an explanation on why and how your answer does solve the OP question.